# How to use xbindkeys to switch workspaces in Gnome overview?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell

Here is my `~/.xbindkeysrc` config:

```
"gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'imports.ui.main.wm._showWorkspaceSwitcher(global.display, null, { get_name() { return `switch-to-workspace-down` } });'"
   b:8

"gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'imports.ui.main.wm._showWorkspaceSwitcher(global.display, null, { get_name() { return `switch-to-workspace-up` } });'"
   b:9
```

It assigns workspace switching to my mouse buttons. And it works everywhere but in Gnome overview (when you press the Super key you can see this overview). Is there anything that I can do to fix it?

I can patch `gnome-shell` if it's needed. But I don't what should be in the patch :)

**My environment**

- Gnome Shell 3.36.4
- Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. It can instead be posted to https://superuser.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/. In either case, make sure to check the corresponding on-topic pages: [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) & [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by using `easystroke` package

```
sudo apt-get install easystroke
```

Answer (score 0):

You could install `xdotool` and get current and max desktop. Then increment by one modulo max. Like so:

```
"xdotool set_desktop $((cur=$(xdotool get_desktop), max=$(xdotool get_num_desktops), (cur + 1) % max))"
```